# MVVM async call in viewmodel : How can I connect azure DB with MVVM

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, mvvm

I'm developing a win phone 8 app using mvvm concept(Data,Group,Model), I completed my app design using this concept.  Now I am trying to connect my app to azure DB, I also connected azure DB with out using MVVM concept through the following code and Its working successfully.

```
var js = new JObject { { "institutionid", obj.institutionid }, { "userid", obj.userid } };
var result = await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync("school_365_create_dynamic_tile", js, System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, null);
```

In the creation of a ViewModel I have to do a call to a service that read data from a Azure Mobile Service using the Azure Mobile Service Sdk.

Sdk apis use async /await to do the work, and I can't do async calls in the ViewModel.

The code is like this for Model class:

```
public class ModelMail : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    //newly added
    public Group Mail { get; set; }
    public Group OutBox { get; set; }
    public Group Draft { get; set; }
    public Group SendItems { get; set; }
    public bool IsDataLoaded { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        //Newly created
        Mail = CreateMail();
        OutBox = CreateOutBox();
        Draft = CreateDraft();
        SendItems = CreateSendItems();
        IsDataLoaded = true;
    }


    private Group CreateDraft()
    {
        Group data = new Group();

        data.Title = "all";
        string[] gataFromDB = new string[] { "sample ", "sample", "sample", "sample" };

        data.Items.Add(new Data { Name_1 = "Nisar Mohamed VM", Subject = "Subject Inbox sample mail subject Inbox sample mail subject Inbox sample mail subject Inbox sample mail subject Inbox sample mail subject 456", Message = "Message This is a sample mail message from nisar This is a sample mail message from nisar This is a sample mail message from nisar This is a sample mail message from nisar This is a sample mail message from nisarThis is a sample mail message from nisar", time = "11:00 AM", IsChecked = false, foreground = "Black", to = "gowthamrajs@hotmail.com", mailFullDateTime = "Fri 9/12 9:25 PM", from = "kkkk@knowledgeq.com" });

        foreach (string dataa in gataFromDB)
        {

            data.Items.Add(new Data { Name_1 = "Nisar Mohamed VM", Subject = "Subject Inbox sample mail subject Inbox sample mail subject Inbox sample mail subject Inbox sample mail subject Inbox sample mail subject 456", Message = "Message This is a sample mail message from nisar This is a sample mail message from nisar This is a sample mail message from nisar This is a sample mail message from nisar This is a sample mail message from nisarThis is a sample mail message from nisar", time = "11:10 AM", IsChecked = false, foreground = "Black", to = "nisr199@hotmail.com", cc = "nisr19@gmail.com", mailFullDateTime = "Fri 9/12 9:25 PM", from = "kkkk@knowledgeq.com" });
        }


        return data;
    }

    private Group CreateOutBox()
    {
        Group data = new Group();

        data.Title = "unread";

        return data;
    }

    private Group  CreateMail()
    {
        Group data = new Group();

        data.Title = "all";

        return data;
    }

    private Group CreateSendItems()
    {
        Group data = new Group();

        data.Title = "all";

        return data;
    }

}
```

How can I

Comment: "I can't do async calls in the ViewModel." is that a requirement? or are you using a framework that does not support async await?

Comment: Thanks sir, yes exactly you are correct, I want to use async in any constructor like CreateDraft() or CreateOutBox() or CreateSendItems(),Because I need to set value for those constructor using azure database.

Comment: then mark them as async use Task and use `Task<T>` e.g. `private  async Task<Group> CreateDraft()`

Comment: It says "Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<KQ_School.ViewModels.Group>' to 'KQ_School.ViewModels.Group'" in  Mail = CreateMail(); where I am creating constr ...

Comment: you have to Await it `Mail = await CreateMail();`
`

Comment: oh sorry, It s working fine but the data is not loading when we are using task. With out using Task the data is loading.

Comment: when we are using await in CreateDraft(), DB data suceesfully loaded but it is not binding.

Comment: It is binding when we have reload the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find my [MSDN article on async data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) helpful. In summary, if you're data binding, then you need to raise `PropertyChanged` when the downloading of the data completes. `Task` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so it needs a bit of help. I have a type `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>` in my article that can be used as a data-bindable wrapper for an async operation.

You'd start the asynchronous operation in your constructor, and create a `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>` that contains the (data-bindable) results:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public MyViewModel()
  {
    Mail = new NotifyTaskCompletion<Group>(CreateMailAsync());
  }

  public NotifyTaskCompletion<Group> Mail { get; private set; }

  private async Task<Group> CreateMailAsync()
  {
    // Azure calls go here
  }
}
```

Then, your data binding code can use the properties on `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>` to update the UI:

```
<Grid>
  <!-- Busy indicator -->
  <Label Content="Loading..." Visibility="{Binding Mail.IsNotCompleted, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

  <!-- Results -->
  <Label Content="{Binding Mail.Result.Title}" Visibility="{Binding Mail.IsSuccessfullyCompleted, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

  <!-- Error details -->
  <Label Content="{Binding Mail.ErrorMessage}" Background="Red" Visibility="{Binding Mail.IsFaulted, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Note that you need some extra states in your application UI. Specifically, a "loading" state for when the operation is in progress; and an "error" state for when the operation asynchronously fails.